# How to increase font size in front-end in Mathematica 12?

Tags: front-end

In Mathematica 11 it was very easy: Inspector options (Global Preferences) -> Global Options -> PrivateFrontEndOptions -> XDefaultApplicationFont. Then change for example for 14pt: "Bitstream Vera Sans-14". But in Mathematica 12 there is no XDefaultApplicationFont! How change font size now? System Linux Mint 18 (Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: (Global Preferences) | Formatting Options | Font Options | Font Size

Comment: @Edmund  Does not work. Nothing changed at whole.

Comment: Humm, that seems to only change the font size of the input lines in the documentation.  The Magnification setting in the same location increases everything. You may need to close and reopen a workbook if it does not immediately magnify.

Comment: @Edmund I do not need increse fonts of the input lines in notebook. I ask about increasing fonts in menu - File, Edit, Insert and so on.